# Spring Boot Error org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring-boot

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'producer' defined in file [C:\Users\guptadee\Projects\Server\Vista\docstash_api_migration\target\classes\com\adp\avs\tax\form\DocStashElasticMigration\Service\Producer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1201) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at com.adp.avs.tax.form.DocStashElasticMigration.DocStashElasticMigrationApplication.main(DocStashElasticMigrationApplication.java:29) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

> Migration.java

```
@Service
public class Migration {

    @Autowired
    private TransportClient transportClient;

    @Autowired
    ClientDao clientDao;

    @Value("#{'${quarterly.form}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> quarterlyForm;

    @Value("#{'${yearly.form}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> yearlyForm;

    @Value("${threadCount:5}")
    private int threadCount;


    private final String oldIndex = "taxdocument";

    private final String newTaxformIndex = "";

    private final String newDocumentIndex = "";

    public static String type = "document";


    public void migratetoNewIndex(int year, int qtr) throws Exception{
        //Creating BlockingQueue of size 2000
        BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<OutputDocument>(2000);
        final Map<String,List<OrganizationUnit>> organizationUnitMap = clientDao.getAllOrg(String.valueOf(year).substring(2), String.valueOf(qtr));
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue,year,qtr);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        producerThread.start();
        List<Thread> consumerList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i=0;i<threadCount;i++) {
            Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue, organizationUnitMap);
            Thread T1 = new Thread(consumer);
            T1.start();
            consumerList.add(T1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < consumerList.size(); i++) {
            consumerList.get(i).join();
        }
        System.out.println("Producer and Consumer has been started");

    }

}
```

> Producer.java

```
@Component
public class Producer implements Runnable {

    @Autowired
    private TransportClient transportClient;

    @Value("#{'${quarterly.form}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> quarterlyForm;

    @Value("#{'${yearly.form}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> yearlyForm;

    @Value("${threadCount:5}")
    private int threadCount;

    private final String oldIndex = "taxdocument";

    private final String type = "document";

    private int year;

    private int qtr;


    private BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> queue;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> q, int year,int qtr) {
        this.queue = q;
        this.year=year;
        this.qtr=qtr;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        List subcatecory = new ArrayList();
        subcatecory.addAll(quarterlyForm);
        try {
            List<String> yearQtr = new ArrayList<String>();
            yearQtr.add(year + "/" + qtr);
            if (qtr == 4) {
                subcatecory.addAll(yearlyForm);
                yearQtr.add(String.valueOf(year));
            }
            SearchResponse scrollResp = transportClient.prepareSearch(oldIndex)
                    .setTypes(type)
                    .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
                    .setSize(1000)
                    .setQuery(boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("subCategoryCode.codeValue", subcatecory))
                            .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("applicationData.yearQuarter", yearQtr)))
                    .get(); //max of 100 hits will be returned for each scroll

            if (scrollResp.getHits().getTotalHits() > 0) {
                OutputDocument outputDocument = null;
                Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                List<OutputDocument> documentList = new ArrayList<OutputDocument>();
                do {
                    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
                        responseMap = hit.sourceAsMap();
                        responseMap.remove("storeKey");
                        outputDocument = mapper.convertValue(responseMap, OutputDocument.class);
                        queue.put(outputDocument);
                    }
                    scrollResp = transportClient.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).execute().actionGet();
                } while (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0); // Zero hits mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.

                //exit message to child threads
                for(int i=0; i<threadCount; i++) {
                    OutputDocument exitMessage = new OutputDocument();
                    exitMessage.setItemID("exit");
                    queue.put(exitMessage);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The message is clear: No bean of type `BlockingQueue` is found.

You annotated your class as

```
@Component
public class Producer implements Runnable
```

Hence Spring will try to initialize a singleton bean of that kind.

As you declared a constructor:

```
public Producer(BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> q, int year,int qtr) {
    this.queue = q;
    this.year=year;
    this.qtr=qtr;

}
```

So Spring will try to use that constructor to init the bean.

But first argument `BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> q` is not found hence the exception.

You need to provide a bean of that type:

```
@Bean
BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> createBlockingQueue() {
...
}
```

After this bean is provided, spring will complain about `year`, `qtr` too. So you must provide those bean for it.
**Edit**

You have serious problem in your dependency management.

If you declare your `Producer` as `@Component`, you should inject it to your `Migration` class instead of manually create it.

Answer (score 1):

See public Producer(BlockingQueue q, int year,int qtr)
You dont declared factory instancequalifying bean of type 
'java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue'  BlockingQueue
You could add factory method or factory bean

```
@Bean
public BlockingQueue<OutputDocument> createBlockingQueue() {

}
```